# Read zookeeper transaction logs- Human understandable format

Tags: apache-zookeeper

We make Zookeeper key value changes from zkCli.sh and we would want to track what Key was changed and what is its value.

ZK datadirlogs are stored in /data/zookeeper/log/version-2/log.40084828c

That is in Binary, to get in human understandable format we are using below command:
java -cp /opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar org.apache.zookeeper.server.LogFormatter /data/zookeeper/log/version-2/log.40084828c

**Our ASK**: when we check logs it is showing us info on what key was changed but it doesnt show what was old and new value. Can you please let us know how we can get New value for that property??

**Excerpts from Logs**:
2/25/19 4:11:01 AM CST session 0x168f68d70df0dcc cxid 0x1 zxid 0x40084adc7 setData '/test/path/key1,#687474703a2f2f65787465726e616c2d626c75d6f69632d6465762d3034312e617070732e676370757363312d622e6c6c652e6f63662e6b6f686c732e636f6d2f,11